# Is a higher capacitance rating ok for filtering?

Tags: power, capacitor, pcb, filtering

I am newer to electronic design and bought the mpu6050 sensor chip, which the documentation can be found here:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/TDK-InvenSense-MPU-6050_C24112.pdf

It says that pin 20 connects to 2.2nf cap to ground, however, I don't have one that small. The smallest I currently have is 100nf. I believe that the cap is used for power filtering.

Is ok to use that large of a value in replacement, can I hook up a few in series, or do I need to go and buy the 2.2nf rated ones?

Comment: That is not a simple power filter cap, it is a cap for a charge pump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet recommends 2.2nF X7R +/-10% 50V rating for the charge pump.

It’s quite possible that 100nF will function, but personally I would use the recommended type, including the voltage rating and dielectric type.

There are possible side effects to using a part that different without detailed knowledge of the internals, such as instability or damage to the part.